# My single ElasticSearch node for local access on a VPS is closing down after bootstrap checks

Tags: elasticsearch, localhost, vps, jvm-arguments

I'm trying to run ElasticSearch on a VPS, Virtual Private Server. I'm not expecting many simultaneous search requests at this stage so I'm simply trying to run one single node and communicate with it locally inside the VPS using curl(localhost:9200) from PHP. So I imagine that I don't need any 'transport' connection on port 9300 for communication between nodes.

When I first tried to run ElasticSearch out of the box I got the following:

```
[2017-09-09T14:39:47,682][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: BindTransportException[Failed to bind to [9300-9400]]; nested: BindException[Cannot assign requested address];
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:127) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:114) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:67) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:122) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:88) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:91) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:84) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.BindTransportException: Failed to bind to [9300-9400]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.bindToPort(TcpTransport.java:793) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.bindServer(TcpTransport.java:758) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.doStart(Netty4Transport.java:173) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:69) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.doStart(TransportService.java:209) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.startAbstractLifecycleComponent.java:69) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.start(Node.java:692) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:277) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:360) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:123) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:128) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:554) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1258) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:501) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:486) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:980) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:250) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:365) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:462) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_144]
[2017-09-09T14:39:48,471][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Ejdd-bH] stopping ...
[2017-09-09T14:39:48,474][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Ejdd-bH] stopped
[2017-09-09T14:39:48,474][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Ejdd-bH] closing ...
[2017-09-09T14:39:48,484][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Ejdd-bH] closed
```

So I tried setting in elasticsearch.yml

```
transport.type: local
```

But then I still got:

```
[2017-09-09T14:37:49,035][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [Ejdd-bH] publish_address {local[1]}, bound_addresses {local[1]}
[2017-09-09T14:37:49,045][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [Ejdd-bH] bound or publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address, enforcing bootstrap checks
ERROR: [2] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
[2]: system call filters failed to install; check the logs and fix your configuration or disable system call filters at your own risk
[2017-09-09T14:37:49,054][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Ejdd-bH] stopping ...
[2017-09-09T14:37:49,059][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Ejdd-bH] stopped
[2017-09-09T14:37:49,060][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Ejdd-bH] closing ...
[2017-09-09T14:37:49,072][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Ejdd-bH] closed
```

I can't change the setting for vm.max_map_count since that requires root access which I don't have on a VPS.
But why is it saying "non-loopback or non-link-local address"? Is it because I am on a VPS instead of a dedicated server? I guess that it's not complaining about the transport which is solved. I guess that it's complaining about the 9200 that I need in order to build and search the index. Is there anything I can do?

I tried adding to elasticsearch.yml

```
http.host: localhost
network.host: localhost
transport.host: localhost
http.bind_host: localhost
http.publish_host: localhost
```

but those didn't cause any change.

Then for research purposes I tried

```
http.enabled: false
```

but even that didn't change anything; it still shut down with the same messages.

Comment: Did you use a Docker img? If so, you will need to increase vm.max_map_count, ask your host to do so - see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/docker.html#docker-cli-run-prod-mode

Comment: I simply decompressed the .tar.gz file. Is increasing vm.max_map_count needed even if I only want to bind to the localhost?

Comment: Yes, it is  a common problem with java apps

Comment: Oh well... My host says that they can't make changes like that on their VPS servers.